# List Sends aren't going through Gmail

Tags: lightning-experience, send-email

I am working with a customer to evaluate the "[Send through External Email Services](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_sendthroughexternal_overview.htm&type=5)" with a Gmail connection.

We have enabled the feature and connected their users' accounts to Gmail.

If they send a 1 off email directly to a Lead/Contact, we get the DKIM, SPF, DMARC results we are expecting. DKIM and SPF both validate with their domain and DMARC alignment succeeds.

If we do a List Send, DKIM and SPF technically pass, but DMARC fail because of alignment.  The From address for the SPF record is a salesforce.com one, and not the user's Domain.  So while it validates successfully, we miss on alignment.

Is there a configuration I missed or an option we can use to get the List Sends to use the Send through Gmail too?  Or is this just not supported yet?

Comment: This functionality is related to Marketing Cloud, no?

Comment: No, within lightning, when looking at a list view, you can check the box(es) next to records and from the drop down action list, "Send List Email" to the selected recipients.

Comment: Ok, you might want to be careful with your terminology then. The terms you use make it sound very much like you are using MC. See also: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_email_send.htm&type=5